# NSIS_Simple_Service_Plugin : Invalid command: SimpleSC::InstallService

Tags: nsis

Hello I am new to NSIS I am creating an service through NSIS Service Lib.

When i compile the file i am getting the following error.

```
Invalid command: SimpleSC::InstallService
```

Up to now i have done the following things

I copied the .dll file to the plugin folder and i copied the following code into my file is any thing wrong with my code Please help me.

This is my code:

```
Section

SimpleSC::InstallService "Apache2.2" "Apache2.2" "16" "2" '"$INSTDIR\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"' "" "" ""
Pop $0 

 SectionEnd
```

Any one help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message usually means it cannot find the plugin. If you are using v3.0 alpha then you need to put the .dll in the correct subdirectory inside the plugin directory or use `!addplugindir`.

MakeNSIS lists all the plugins it knows about and the functions they export when you compile with -v4, make sure the plugin exports the function you are trying to call...